# azure ad conditional access with MFA

Tags: azure-active-directory

If my app, sends following request where client-id is representing one app registered in AAD

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/5abbc4c8-c6a0-4265-b75fhjke869050510/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=e849cb01-adc6-4856-8d46-d3a1a7186c06 &
response_type=code &
scope= https://graph.microsoft.com/openid &
redirect_uri= https://mybackend.com
```

As you can see there is not any custom web-api requested in the scope param.
All I am interested in is that above req.  must accomplish MFA
So I believe I need one CA-policy with MFA requirement.
And for that  which  app should be in the cloud-resource-picker blade of CA-policy so that the CA policy is triggered and MFA is performed ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should select the Azure AD app whose client id is `e849cb01-adc6-4856-8d46-d3a1a7186c06`.

Like this:

[image]